# p5play thingy not going back and forth

Tags: javascript

I am experiencing problems with enemy movement in my code. I have created a group of enemies, but their movement is not working properly. I want the guys to simply go back and forth. Here is the code that I have written (I use p5play):

```js
let enemys;
function setup() {
  enemys = new Group();
  enemys.w = 80;
  enemys.h = 60;
  enemys.layer = 1;
  enemys.drag = 0;
  enemys.friction = 0;
  enemys.bounciness = 0;
  enemys.image = "assets/pngegg.png";
  enemys.collider = "kinematic";
  
  let enemy = new enemys.Sprite(150, 120, 20, 29);
}

function enemyMovement() {
  enemys.vel.x=1.5;
  enemys.rotation = 0;
  enemys.drag = 0;
  enemys.friction = 0;
  if (enemys.x > 450) {
    enemys.vel.x = -1.5;
  } else if (enemys.x < 100) {
    enemys.vel.x = 1.5;
  }
}
```

I am looking for advice on how to fix my enemy movement code.

Comment: What specifically is intended and goes wrong? Is it possible to provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help demonstrate?